# Is every subfield of cyclotomic field a kernel field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory

Let $Q[d]$ be a cyclotomic field over $Q$ by adjoining $d-$th primitive root of unity. Let $K\subset Q[d]$ be a subfield. Then $K=Q[d]^G$ where $G$ is some $G\leq (Z_d)^\star$. Given any character $\psi$ of $(Z_m)^\star$, one can realize a kernel field by looking at $Q[d]^{Ker(\psi)}$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Every kernel field is a subfield. Is every subfield of cyclotomic field a kernel field?

$\textbf{Q':}$ If not, how to realize any subfield via characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, every subfield is a kernel field, but you are not going to like the argument. This sheds no light on any important insight, it is just a very basic property of kernels of characters and their connection with normal subgroups of a group. So cyclotomic fields, or in fact fields in general are completely irrelevant in the problem.

Given a finite group $G$, every normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ can be written as the intersection of kernels of some irreducible characters of $G$. If these irreducible characters are $\chi_1, \ldots, \chi_k$, so $N=\cap Ker(\chi_i)$, then $N= Ker(\chi)$ where $\chi= \sum \chi_i$.

As $\mathbb{Z}_d^\star$ is commutative, every subgroup is normal in it, so every subgroup is the kernel of some character. 
As the cyclotomic field is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, every subfield is the fixed field of some subgroup, so the assertion follows trivially.

Comment: This is a dumb question. Why is $\chi=\sum_i\chi_i$ is a character? There is no reason $\chi(ab)=\chi(a)\chi(b)$ here. Maybe there is some orthogonality used here? Thanks.

Comment: Again, general character theory. The sum of characters is always a character, over any group. Just put together the matrix representation from those of the representations corresponding to the characters, making block diagonal matrices.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.